# On Iphone, how do I implement a button that will open up a website?

Tags: iphone

From my Objective C iPhone app, I want a user to click on a "Register" for account button and then open up a registration page on my website.  What is the code on the iPhone to open up a website in response to a user action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a UIButton and assign the action to a method like this:

```
- (IBAction)register:(id)sender {

     //you'll want to subclass UIViewController  
     SomeViewController *webViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc]init];
     [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
     [webViewController release];
}
```

Your SomeViewController will have a webview that load's your register page.  Then in your "SomeViewController"'s viewDidLoad, do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/register"]];
    //this is a webview that you either created in -loadView or IB
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: I also found a quicker way to load the website: UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?g=London"]];

Comment: That way works, however it makes your user leave your app.  I don't know about you but I hate it when an app quits for something that it can do why still running.  They might decide it's too much trouble to register for you app.  Running it in a WebView is good UX.